# Android currency format returning different currency symbol

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, formatting, currency

I'm trying to do currency formatting in my text editor. I wrote some code and I have a problem. NumberFormat is returning different currency symbols on different devices.

Here's my source code:

```
    final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    transfer_maney.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                transfer_maney.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");


                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                String formatted = nf.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed / 100));
                current = formatted;

                if (formatted.contains("$")) {
                    formatted = formatted.replace("$", "");
                }
                transfer_maney.setText(formatted);
                transfer_maney.setSelection(formatted.length());

                transfer_maney.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

My goal is to always return `$` symbol and then remove it. As I said, on different devices I have different symbols. On some devices I get a `$` symbol, on some `£` symbol. What should I change in my code, so it will always return dollar symbol (`$`) so I can remove it?

I tried to change the `Locale` but it's not working. If anyone knows solution please help me.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a static method `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` that works that way:

```
public final static NumberFormat getCurrencyInstance() {
    return getInstance(Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT), CURRENCYSTYLE);
}
```

As you can see, it returns a `NumberFormat` object with a default `Locale`, not the `Locale` you are setting. That means it depends on user device settings.

---

So, instead of calling `format` on that statically returned instance with default `Locale`:

```
nf.getCurrencyInstance().format(parsed / 100);
```

which is effectively the same as:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(parsed / 100);
```

Use **your** instance with `Locale` that **you've** set:

```
final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
String formatted = nf.format(parsed / 100);
```